# How to set Default for Last Command Line Argument

Tags: bash

So I have this code that will tunnel VNC over SSH and start a session.
It has A argument for the hostname but it's the last argument.
I want to put a default Value for the hostname.
I can't just check if the value is blank because it will show a other argument.

This is the script's syntax:

```
VNC-Over-SSH - Make VNC Connections Over SSH
 
VNC-Over-SSH [options] [hostname]
 
hostname: The Hostname of the VNC Server. Defaults to "server1".
options:
-h, --help                show brief help
-u, --AuthUser=Username       specify an Username. Defaults to System Username.
```

this is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

package="VNC-Over-SSH"
for HOSTNAME; do :; done
while test $# -gt 0; do
  case "$1" in
    -h|--help)
      echo "$package - Make VNC Connections Over SSH"
      echo " "
      echo "$package [options] [hostname]"
      echo " "
      echo "hostname: The Hostname of the VNC Server. Defaults to \"server1\"."
      echo "options:"
      echo "-h, --help                show brief help"
      echo "-u, --AuthUser=Username       specify an Username. Defaults to System Username."
      exit 0
      ;;
    -u)
      shift
      if test $# -gt 0; then
        export USERNAME=$1
      else
        echo "no Username specified"
        exit 1
      fi
      shift
      ;;
    --AuthUser*)
      if [[ "$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//g')" != "" ]] && [[ "$1" != "--AuthUser" ]] ; then
        USERNAME=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//g')
      else
        echo "no Username specified"
        exit 1
      fi
      shift
      ;;
    *)
      break
      ;;
  esac
done

if [ "$USERNAME" == "" ]; then
USERNAME=$USER
fi
export USERNAME

ssh -L 9876:localhost:5900 -N -f -l "$USERNAME" "$HOSTNAME"
vncviewer UserName="$USERNAME" localhost:9876 &
wait -n
kill $(ps aux | grep "ssh -L 9876:localhost:5900 -N -f -l $USERNAME $HOSTNAME" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the loop that processes options is done, check whether there's a `$1` argument. If there is, use that, otherwise use the default.

```
HOSTNAME=${1:-server1}
```

Comment: It'd also be better to use a different variable name, since `HOSTNAME` is normally the current (local) computer's hostname. This is another example of how all-caps variable names can run into conflicts with the many all-caps names that have special meanings.